# How to modify peewee custom fields after save() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

For example, I have a model:

```py
class ExampleModel(Base):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    image = ImageField(size=(200, 200))

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'example'
```

`ImageField` - it's my custom field:

```py
class ImageField(TextField):
    thumb_size: Tuple[int, int] = None

    def __init__(self, size: Tuple[int, int] = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.thumb_size = size

    def db_value(self, value):
        # ...some file upload logic

        return json.dumps({
            'original': original_path,
            'thumbnail': thumbnail_path
        })

    def python_value(self, value):
        return json.loads(value)
```

When i save instance, everything good (`body.image` has a `starlette.datastructures.UploadFile` type):

```py
example: ExampleModel = dict_to_model(ExampleModel, body)
example.save()
```

But, if I check type of `example.image` after saving, it's still have `starlette.datastructures.UploadFile` type. How i can modify image field after saving, or may be after running `db_value()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `python_value()` and `db_value()` are used when reading-from and writing-to the database, respectively. They are *not* the place to perform any magic besides converting the value from one data-type to another, and are solely there to provide Pythonic data-types for values coming from the database cursor.

In other words, you are putting your magic in the wrong place. Put it in the `save()` method, rather than in the field class.

Comment: Yes, but save() method also not a suitable place, for write field level logic in the model. This also violates the concept of DRY.

Comment: Please guide me. How can I correctly override a value from the methods of the `Field` instances?)

Comment: Check out how I've implemented BigBitField in peewee.py. It involves the use of a custom descriptor.